# How to use UIStringDrawing category methods on the #swift String struct?

Tags: ios, swift

How to use UIStringDrawing category methods on the #swift String struct ?
in Objective-C i can calculate the string size by

`CGSize size = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Courier" size:12] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];`

how to use it in swift by String or NSString? （NSString does not contain this api in swift）

and is there any other solution to calculate the string's size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `NSString`'s `boundingRectWithSize(_:options:attributes:context)` method.